# Install XNA 4.0 Visual Studio 2010 Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, xna-4.0

I installed windows 8 a month ago and now want to add xna game studio 4.0 to my visual studio 2010 ultimate. I downloaded the xna installer from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714 and ran the setup. First it said something about compatibility issues but the setup continued. after it finished I restarted the computer and wanted to make a xna project but its not showing in the c# drop-down menu. So i took a look at the %programm files(x86)%/Microsoft viual studio 10.0/Common 7/IDE/extensions/Microsoft, but there was no xna folder. Did I do something wrong or is windows 8 having some issues with vs2010 and xna 4.0?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

XNA is not officially supported on Windows 8 and never will be because Microsoft simply gave up on it.

[This solution](http://www.demonixis.net/blog/installer-xna-4-0-sous-windows-8/) explains how to install XNA on Windows 8 but clearly if you want a stable development environment you will have to develop on a Windows 7 machine but remember that even if you are skilled on XNA, the Framework itself is doomed and bound to disappear.

If you want to keep developing with C# on Windows 8 I can only recommend you move to [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) which is an open source implementation of the XNA 4 API for multiple platforms using the CLR or Mono so basically most of your XNA knowledge can be reused in MonoGame.

Comment: This is how we do it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2012/02/29/10274694.aspx

Answer (score 7):

IF you realy want to keep on programming with XNA 4.0 there is a work around.
Just install the following program (official windows program):

http://www.xbox.com/en-US/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient

This is the windows marketplace client which seems to help a lot, after installing try installing xna again it should work, atleast it did fine on my PC which is running windows 8.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it's correct. And more details here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2012/02/29/10274694.aspx

Comment: I installed VS2010 XNA for windows phone and the install failed. Just installed the Live client and repaired the VS installation and it works fine. This is definitely the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

XNA Game Studio installs a version of the Games for Windows – LIVE Redistributable behind the scenes. Some older versions of the Games for Windows – LIVE Redistributable attempt to install and use a file that is being installed by Windows 8, and the older versions of the redistributable are not compatible with the newer version of the file that is installed by Windows 8. Newer versions of the Games for Windows – LIVE Redistributable are compatible with Windows 8, and if you pre-install the new redistributable before installing XNA Game Studio, setup will recognize that it is already there and use the new version instead of trying to install the old version.

How to work around this issue

If you run into this issue, here are steps that you can use to work around it:

Download and install the latest version of the Games for Windows – LIVE Redistributable from http://www.xbox.com/en-US/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient
If you are installing the Windows Phone SDK 7.1, re-run setup and choose to repair it. This will re-run the previously failing XNA Game Studio installers and they should install correctly this time.
If you are install a standalone XNA Game Studio product, re-run setup and it should install correctly this time.
If you are planning to do Windows Phone development, you should also install the Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 Update after installing the Windows Phone SDK 7.1. This update fixes an issue that prevents the emulator in the Windows Phone SDK 7.1 from working correctly on Windows 8.

Microsoft has NOT given up on XNA as far as I can tell. They just aren't updating the installer yet. Maybe they'll bring it around for 8.1. Who knows?

Answer (score -1):

i have installed windows 8 developper preview

and i wanted to install xna frame work on visual studio 2012

but i had a compatibility issue

so here is what to do to fix this problem

go ahead and download Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate ISO from microsoft

[Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate ISO Microsoft Center Download](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9709972)

Then Burn it on a cd using Burning Tool (Nero Express for exp)

if you dont have cd to burn it you can use Daemon Tools to raise an ISO into a virtual CD/DVD drive

[Here is the Download Link for Daemon tools](http://www.clubic.com/telecharger-fiche10729-daemon-tools-lite.html)

after installing Visual Studio 2010

install the XNA 4.0 FrameWork

restart your pc

and enjoy :)

Answer (score -1):

This is the official solution, where Microsoft's help points you to, to solve this issue:

> How to work around a possible XNA Game Studio or Windows Phone SDK
>   install failure on Windows 8
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2012/02/29/10274694.aspx

And, if you are just trying to get XNA 4.0 working, and have nothing to do with Windows Phone SDK 7.1, then you can just install "Games for Windows – LIVE Redistributable" and then the install of XNA 4.0 should work fine. It did for me.